# Are there any developer tools to see the names of JavaScript functions getting performed on an HTML event?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am trying to debug a web application and I cannot change the code, I can only view the code and run the web application in the browser.

Now there is an event where on changing a dropdown option, another text field is getting changed based on some calculation. But the flow is very difficult because of the complexity of the application and backbone.js implementation and there are no console logging done.

Are there any developer tools through which just as we see HTML elements by inspecting we can also see all the JavaScript functions that are being called?

Comment: Try using the performance tab. Record yourself doing those interaction and you should see a timeline of what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

For inputs you can override `value` property of all inputs on the page with a snippet in Devtools and set a breakpoint inside the setter, then in the right panel you can see the call stack and all functions that were called until the value's change:

```
const prop = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'value');
const override = {...prop, set:function(val){
    debugger;
    return prop.set.call(this,val);
}};

document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => {
    Object.defineProperty(input, 'value', override);
});
```

[image]

If you want to find what code changes your DOM, you could use Devtools `Break on` feature:

Hover your element of interest and select a needed modifiction.

[image]